# php command line print in object not returning

Tags: php, command-line

I am trying to run some php from the command line but the php in my class is not being hit.

```
<?php
print "1";
try {
    print ",2";
    $a = new myClass("");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
print ",3";
```

myClass

```
<?php

class myClass{

    function __construct($var) {
        print "My Class";
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
1,2

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Why is the print in the constructor not outputting to the command line?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you remembering to include the class definition file?

Comment: Exit code of 255 implies that something error'd.  I wonder if the problem is compounded by a shy `display_errors` or `error_reporting` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be doing `$a = new Checkout();` as that is the name of your class, even though you have it in a file named myclass.php probably.  you should have gotten the following error:

```
1
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'myClass' not found in somefile.php on line whateverlineitwas
PHP Stack trace:
,2
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/cdaley/Sites/PHP-1.php:0
```

You are not getting the 3 either because the code is failing and exiting, weird you are not seeing an error.  PS, it throws a fatal error, not an exception, prolly why it did not CATCH it.

Here is the code i am running via command line:

```
<?php
class myClass {

    function __construct($var) {
        print "My Class";
    }
}
    print "1";
try {
    print ",2";
    $a = new myClass("");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
print ",3";

?>
```

Comment: Checkout was a typo it should be myClass()

Comment: if myClass is used, then it runs fine here ;)

Comment: see above in the answer for the formatted code i am running via commandline

Comment: So, i think you are not including the myclass.php file into the file that is running the code that is failing.  Are they both in the same file or different files? This is not like Java where it finds the classes on the classpath, the file has to be included with something like include('myclass.php');

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file

```
include `myClass.php';
```

The path may vary depending on your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Exist status 255 is a fatal error. You should try setting `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

to ensure no errors are masked out. That should help you spot the culprit.